# Where to register a django signal if the receiver function lives in a management command

Tags: python, django, django-signals

I have, effectively, a standalone script, which gets data from an external source and dumps it into the django channel layers. On startup, the script queries the database for all `Product` objects, which tells it which datasources it needs to join. I'm trying to implement a signal which tells the script when a new `Product` instance is saved, so that it can join any further sources that might be necessary.
I'm using the following code:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from home.models import Product


@receiver(post_save, sender=Product)
def test(sender, **kwargs):
    print("SUCESS------------------------------------------------------{}".format(sender))
```

This script lives in `f/data_sources/management/commands/source.py`, the product model lives in `home/models.y`. Apparently, I need to somehow import the 'test' function defined in source.py, but I'm not sure how to. It's a huge script, do I import the whole thing? I'm not even sure what the import command would be.

Comment: Using a signal will only work if the products are saved by the standalone script. It won't work if the product is saved by another process (e.g. via a webpage). I think it would be better to update [your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50681733/django-signals-does-a-model-automatically-send-post-save), rather than splitting information across two questions.

Comment: Right, is there any way around that? I've deleted the old question, since this contains all of the same information and more

Comment: The product model defines the name of a datasource (actually a pubnub channel). This script reads the name of the pubnub channel from each of the product instances, and subscribes to that channel, on pubnub. It then pushes the data into the django channel layer. This works perfectly, the issue, is that if a new product is created, the script does not know to update its list of subscriptions. I thought a signal might be used to tell it 'product x has been created with pubnub channel y', and then it would react appropriately.